# Data query working in oracle sqlplus but not in PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I have connected a oracle database with PHP. When I try to query a data in sqlplus it works. But when I try to query in PHP, it doesn't work(It doesn't show any error or nothing). My emp_id is number.

```php
        <p> $query = "select order_id from ordered_by where order_emp_id =".$emp_id."and order_done='N'";

        $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);

        $r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);

        $value="";

        while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) 

        {

            foreach ($row as $item) 

            {

                $item!== null ? htmlentities($item) :'NULL';

                $value =$item;



            }
```

Comment: What  does the meaning of "it does not work ?" An error appear ?

Comment: try attaching the schema name to the `where` clause like `schema_name.ordered_by`

Comment: your "emp_id" is string or int?

Answer (score 2):

Put a space after  `=".$emp_id."`

```
$query = "select order_id from ordered_by where order_emp_id =".$emp_id." and order_done='N'";
```